# Show a certain expression is differentiable a certain number of times

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm working on a problem as stated:

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and let
$$
F_n(x) = \int_0^x (x - t)^{n-1} f(t) \, dt \, .
$$
Prove that $F_n$ is n times differentiable.

And I've tried applying the FTC to get that

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x (x - t)^{n-1} f(t) \, dt 
= \left[ (x - t)^{n-1} f(t) \right]_{t=x}(x)
$$

Which is always zero? (unless n=1) I'm a little confused by this. Is there something about the FTC that fails with the dependence on $x$ in the integrand? I'm hoping someone can help point me back in the right direction. Maybe the FTC is not the right way to do this but it seems like the obvious choice.

Comment: Your integrand involves $x$, which is also variable you are differentiating over; you can't apply the FTC, because the integrand is not a function independent of $x$. The FTC says that if $f(t)$ is a fixed integrable function, then $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$; here, you are not always integrating the same function.

Comment: Look up the Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: You could even put $f(t)$ equal a constant $(t=0)$, and only treat the first term of the integral. Since differentiation of some function exponent to $n-1$ gives a change in the exponent to $n-2$, then that is proven when it is n-times differentiated, hence $n-1-n=-1$. So you have a function exponent to $-1$, hence it is differentiable

Answer (score 1):

Let $$G_n(x,y)=\int\limits_0^x(y-t)^{n-1}f(t)\,dt$$
Then $F_n(x)=G_n(x,x).$ Applying the chain rule gives
$$\displaylines{{dF_n\over dx}(x)={\partial G_n\over \partial x}(x,x)+{\partial G_n\over \partial y}(x,x)\\ =0+(n-1)\int\limits_0^x(x-t)^{n-2}f(t)\,dt=(n-1)F_{n-1}(x)}$$
We have
$$F_1(x)=\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,dt,$$ i.e. $F_1$ is differentiable. By induction we conclude that $F_n$ is $n$ times differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

When both the bounds and the integrand depend on $x$, differentiating the integral must reflect all these dependencies. For a general theorem, see e.g. the section "General form with variable limits" of the [page "Leibniz integral rule" on Wikipedia in english](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), or the section "Forme générale unidimensionnelle" of the [page "Intégrale paramétrique" on Wikipedia in french](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9grale_param%C3%A9trique). Here, to get the whole $F'_n(x)$, you have to add (to the term you wrote, and which is indeed $0$ unless $n=1$) another term : $(n-1)\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-2}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ .